External module .d.ts file: TS7010 constructor which lacks return -type annotation , implicitly has an any return type
dayjs module contains index.d.ts in which we have this code:
export declare interface Dayjs { 
constructor(config?:ConfigType)
...
}

It causes this error: error TS7010: 'constructor', which leaks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
I tried to interfer again the type, did not work :
dayjs.d.ts:
export declare namespace dayjs{
interface Dayjs {
constructor(config?:ConfigType):Dayjs
}
}

any solution? without disabling noImplicitAny config
